# HTTP request with Perl to a utf-8 URI (some non-ascii chars inside) throws a 404 Not Found error

Tags: perl, utf-8, uri, lwp

I'm trying to request an URL which has some characters that are non-ASCII, for example: [http://perry.wikia.com/wiki/Página_principal](http://perry.wikia.com/wiki/P%C3%A1gina_principal) which has an `á` symbol.

I've tried with LWP::UserAgent but it throws a 404 Not found error:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use utf8;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use Encode qw(decode encode);

my $br = LWP::UserAgent->new;
#~ my $url = 'http://perry.wikia.com/wiki/Página_principal'; # doesn't work either
my $url = encode('UTF-8','http://perry.wikia.com/wiki/Página_principal');
my $response = $br->get($url);
if ($response->{success}) {
    my $html = $response->{content};
} else {
  die "Unexpected error requesting $url : " . $response->status_line;
}
```

I've tried with HTTP::Tiny too, same result:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use utf8;
use HTTP::Tiny;
use Encode qw(decode encode);

my $url = 'http://perry.wikia.com/wiki/Página_principal';
#~ my $url = encode('UTF-8','http://perry.wikia.com/wiki/Página_principal'); # doesn't work either
my $response = HTTP::Tiny->new->get($url);
if ($response->{success}) {
    my $html = $response->{content};
} else {
  die "Unexpected error requesting $url : " . $response->{status};
}
```

Comment: You've neglected to do the URI encoding:  `http://perry.wikia.com/wiki/P%C3%A1gina_principal` is what you actually want to GET.

Comment: Check out [URI::Encode](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI::Encode) or [URI::Escape](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI::Escape)

Comment: I forgot to mention, I tried to use URI::Escape to escape the URI but it doesn't work either, it returns the same 404 error. Actually, If you try to just do a request to the URI already encoded: http://perry.wikia.com/wiki/P%C3%A1gina_principal it does not work :/

Comment: Tested with URI:Encode, same URI output and same 404 result :(

Comment: Are you sure that this URL isn't actually a 404?  Chrome and curl are giving me 404s.

Comment: you're absolutely right @oalders. I've missed it because, from the browser, the website seemed to response an actual page instead of an 404 Error.

Comment: @Akronix perhaps best to close or remove the question then?

Comment: @oalders I voted to close it as "Unclear what you're asking" (I dind't find any other reason closer), but it requires 3 more votes to be closed :/
On the other hand, I think that It could be useful for somebody else, so I thought it's better to not remove it.

Comment: @Akronix ok, in that case I added an answer, to save anyone from having to read all the comments. :)

Comment: @oalders all right. there you go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug in any of the Perl modules.  This URL actually does return a 404.